Indian citizen applying for Singapore visa from US
I'm an Indian citizen currently in the US. I want to know what the procedure of applying for a Singapore visa is. I do not have any contact in Singapore. If you could let me know what the process is, that would be great.

I think Singapore has electronic visa for Indians

@SaranshSharma You still has to send in the passport to embassy via agent, unless your are applying via PR/Citizen.

You have to find a travel agent based in the US. They can apply on your behalf. You need the following usually.

6 months of bank statements.
Proof of employment (if you are employed).
Your passport.
Flight tickets and hotel accommodation.
Photo.

You will get your visa in 5-15 days after application and you will be getting a validity of 1-3 months from date of approval. You have to land in SG before the expiry date of the visa. You will get a 1-month stay (extendable). The cost can vary.
There is no online application, unless you have a friend/relative who is an SG citizen or PR. In that case, it's far easier and you will get the visa in one day.

Visa requirements for Indian nationals Singapore Govt Website
I will try to summarise though this is not the place for asking such questions.
According to the website and personal experience, you can apply online but it has to be done online where an agent, a resident or a citizen of Singapore can apply on your behalf.
In your case, you should try and find a local agent, meaning a tour operator or a certified agent that will help you file your visa at your location.
I don’t know of services in Washington but in India we have a list of authorised agents who provide this service for a fee, and the visa comes in three days.
